# How to check if an image file is animated in Golang?

Tags: image, go

I'm still new to Go and I wanted to port a Python project to it.

The project has several requirements, one of them is to store information about a big amount of files into an SQLite database, and that information includes:

1. A hash for the file.
2. The type of file (if it is an image, a video, document, code, etc according only to its extension).

In the case of a file being of type `image`, **I need to know if the image is animated or not**. And I need to support `.gif`, `.webp` and `.avif` extensions.

In Python I'm simply using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.seek)'s `seek` method to check if the frame `1` exists. And I'm using the package [pillow-avif-plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pillow-avif-plugin/) to add avif support to Pillow. This works perfectly for all mentioned image formats.

Anyway to do the same in Go?

I would prefer not to call an external program for every file since I suppose it would harm the performance.

Comment: You can check the magic number of file. https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype

Answer (score 0):

There is a type [Paletted](https://pkg.go.dev/image#Paletted) in image package. You can use standard type assertion to check for this type.

For example (where fileread implements io.Reader):

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "image"
    _ "image/png"
    _ "image/gif"
    _ "image/jpeg"
)
// ...
imageF, _, err = image.Decode(fileread)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error with image decode")
}
switch imageF.(type) {
case *image.Paletted:
    fmt.Println("This can be a gif image")
// proceed with your code 
}
```

That definitely works for *.gif